# Jquery PHP push?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, push

I need to implement real-time page data update with php and jquery.
(I found www.ape-project.org/ but it seems site is down)
Is any other solutions?

Very TNX!

Comment: Do you mean like if something happens on server -- update in the browser in client?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out Comet:

> Comet is a web application model in
>   which a long-held HTTP request allows
>   a web server to push data to a
>   browser, without the browser
>   explicitly requesting it.[1][2] Comet
>   is an umbrella term, encompassing
>   multiple techniques for achieving this
>   interaction. All these methods rely on
>   features included by default in
>   browsers, such as JavaScript, rather
>   than on non-default plugins. The Comet
>   approach differs from the original
>   model of the web, in which a browser
>   requests a complete web page at a
>   time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do streaming (sending multiple messages over a single long lived, low latency connection), you probably need a comet server.  Check out http://cometdaily.com/maturity.html for details on a variety of server implementations (I am the maintainer of one of them - Meteor).

If you are happy to reconnect after each message is received, you can do without complicated servers and transports and just use long polling - where you make an ajax request and the server simply sleeps until it has something to send back.   But you will end up with LOTS of connections hanging off your web server, so if you're using a conventional web server like Apache, make sure it's configured to handle that.  By default Apache doesn't like having more than a few hundred concurrent connections.

Answer (score -1):

There is lots of solutions to do this...
Depending on what is your data, how your data are organized and stored (mysql ?).

Your question is too open to have a real answer.

Comment: I see, my goal is to provide real-time data update from php\mysql serverside. Exmpl: players are making bids for goods and we need to show it to sellers in realtime